# Closed map of schemes and Frobenius reciprocity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

A map of locales $f : X  \rightarrow Y$ is closed if it satisfies the [reciprocity relation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+morphism#between_locales) $f_*(f^*(X) \vee Y) \cong X \vee f_* (Y)$.

How can we express a that a map of schemes $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is closed in terms of the direct image $f^*$ and inverse image $f_*$? Is this equivalent to the same reciprocity relation?

Is there some tweaking of the setting for locales which gives rise to a similar reciprocity condition for schemes?

Note: here $f_*$ and $f^*$ are the direct image and inverse image functors between categories of quasicoherent sheaves on $X$ and $Y$.

Any insights are appreciated.

---

The map $f^*((f_* M) \otimes N) \rightarrow M \otimes f_* (N)$ arises as the adjunct of the map
$$ f^*  ((f_*  M )  \otimes N) \rightarrow (f^* f_* M) \otimes (f^* N) \rightarrow M \otimes (f^* N)$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $f^*$ and $f_*$? If you mean on all (abelian) sheaves, it's just a question about topological spaces. Or are you thinking specifically of quasi-coherent sheaves or sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules?

Comment: quasi-coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

Comment: I don't know what locales are but there is a projection formula for intersection theory of cycles which looks superficially similar.

Comment: @Asvin thanks, I'll look into that.